# Portable Python (Mac -> Windows)

Tags: python, portability, pygame

I have a lovely Macbook now, and I'm enjoying coding on the move. I'm also enjoying coding in Python. However, I'd like to distribute the end result to friends using Windows, as an executable.

I know that Py2Exe does this, but I don't know how portable Python is across operating systems. Can anyone offer any advice? I'm using PyGame too.

Many thanks

Comment: Check http://www.python.org for answers to this question.  Python is perfectly portable.  Do it all the time.  `.EXE` files are not portable.  By definition.  What are you trying to do?  Why mention `.EXE` files, which are not portable?  Please expand your question to provide more information.

Comment: What I meant was, will python coded on a Mac run on a Windows machine, or are there little platform-specific sugar all over the place. I want to compile to EXE later on Windows, but it has to be runnable as Python in order to compile it to EXE. :P

Comment: Please **update** your question.  Please do not comment on your question.  Please **update** the question to be complete and correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I experienced huge difficult with all the Exe builder, py2exe , cx_freeze etc. Bugs and errors all the time , keep displaying an issue with atexit module.

I find just by including the python distro way more convinient. There is one more advantage beside ease of use.

Each time you build an EXE for a python app, what you essential do is include the core of the python installation but only with the modules your app is using. But even in that case your app may increase from a mere few Kbs that the a python module is to more than 15 mbs because of the inclusion of python installation.

Of course installing the whole python will take more space but each time you send your python apps they will be only few kbs long. Plus you want have to go to the hussle of bundling the exe each time you change even a coma to your python app. Or I think you do , I dont know if just replacing the py module can help you avoid this.

In any case installing python and pygame is as easy as installing any other application in windows. In linux via synaptic is also extremly easy.

MACOS is abit tricky though. MACOS already come with python pre installed, Snow leopard has 2.6.1 python installed. However if you app is using a python later than that and include the install of python with your app, you will have to instruct the user to set via "GET INFO -> open with" the python launcher app which is responsible for launcing python apps to use your version of python and not the onboard default 2.6.1 version, Its not difficult and it only takes a few seconds, even a clueless user can do this.

Python is extremely portable, python pygame apps cannot only run unchanged to the three major platform , Windows , MACOS ,Linux . They can even run on mobile and portable devices as well. If you need to build app that runs across platform , python is dead easy and highly recomended.

Answer (score 3):

The Python *scripts* are reasonably portable, as long as the interpreter and relevant libraries are installed. Generated .exe and .app files are not.

Comment: "The relevant libraries" can and do frequently rely on platform specific functionality. e.g. Twisted's kqueue functionality, or `os.fork`. Programs must always be written with the principle of portability in mind.

Comment: Excellent, this is just what I needed to know. I'll compile everything up on Windows when I'm all done. Thanks to others who responded. :)

Answer (score 2):

Py2exe generates Windows executables, so they will only work on the Windows Platform.  The FAQ at http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ has more information on how it all works.  Essentially it provides what is needed to run on Win9x as well as more current platforms.  NOTE: the FAQ mentions some potential gotchas with character encodings and the work arounds.

With python, it is common enough on Unix based systems, as several Linux distributions have their custom maintenance scripts written in the language.  So the Python scripts will be just as portable as Ruby scripts, etc.  As long as the target machine has the interpreter and you are not using external programs that are only on one type of platform, others will be able to use your work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to include Linux in your portability criteria, it's worth remembering that many distributions still package 2.6 (or even 2.5), and will probably be a version behind in the 3.x series as well (I'm assuming your using 2.x given the PyGame requirement though).

Versions of PyGame seem to vary quite heavily between distros as well.

Comment: That's okay, no one plays games on Debian. *runs*

Comment: lol. Well there is always WINE , Ubuntu runs Guild Wars perfectly and I suspect Debian will too. The ability to run windows games along with linux games, makes Linux a quite good game platform. But gaming is not linux strong point but then its not Macos either. Personally for gaming I prefer a console, but I dont play games anymore. Modern games are all about great graphics, they are extremely boring.